# 毎度処理させるか変数に格納するかの見極め方について

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

お世話になっております。

都度更新される情報において、いつも以下のことで思い悩むことがあります。
例えば、キャラクターがマップ上を歩き視界範囲に何があるかチェックするようなシーンです。歩くので座標がいつも変わります。視力はだいたいが固定です（メガネ、コンタクト、晴れた日、雨の日、霧の日があるかも知れません）。
・毎度処理させるか
・中間値（ここでは視力）を変数に保管しとき、これを元に処理を簡略させるか

ハードのスペックとか、プログラム言語の性質とかあるかも知れません。その知識や調べ方が分からなく、そこまでハードリソースに逼迫した環境でもありません。
アプリを作成しているのでiPhone、Swift4になります。

一般的にはどちらを選択する方が多いのでしょうか？

ビルドして検証してみて「負荷がなければ毎度処理で良い」で判断するものなのでしょうか？
他の処理でその変数を参照することがない、且つ、CPU負荷時間よりも一般的にメモリ参照時間がボトルネックになるならば、毎度処理が良いものなのでしょうか？
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 短いお返事

ハードリソースに逼迫した環境でないなら、
まずは簡単に作れる、きれいな書き方をしましょう。
リソース(CPU負荷,メモリ,ネットワーク等)が実際に問題になったら、
全体をプロファイラによって計測し、最適化を考えましょう。
コードをきれいに書くことで、結果として最適化をすばやく効果的に行う事ができるでしょう。

## 考え方を含めたお返事

パレートの法則といわれる経験則があります。

これは、全体のたった1％〜25%程度のプログラムが、
処理時間のうち7５〜99%の間働いているという現象です。
同じように、全体のたった1〜25%程度のプログラムが、
メモリのうち75〜99%を使用してしまうという現象もあります。

ここからわかることは、1つ1つのコードで、
CPUのため、またはメモリのために良くなるような形で
プログラムを書くことを思い悩んだとしても
少なくともその3/4は、ほとんど無意味になってしまう……ということです。

また「早すぎる最適化」という言葉があります。
これはコードに対する高速化を早すぎるタイミングで行うことで
結果としてコードを複雑化させてしまい、より大きな視点で考えたとき
逆の最適化(不最適化)になってしまう事を言います。

つまりプログラムを後で書き換えやすい単純な形で書かなかったことで
本当に一番問題になるプログラム「1%のコード」が見つかった時に、
そこを書き換えることがなかなかできなくなっていて、
良い結果が得られないということです。

普段のコードではCPUやメモリのことを、どちらも気にせずに
「とりあえず単純でわかりやすく、かつ作ってしまいやすい書き方」でやってしまうほうが、
結果として最適化にもつながります。

結論として **簡単だと感じる書き方** にしてしまいましょう。そして測り、改善しましょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変わかりやすく納得もできることができました。「まずは自分も含め後から見やすいように簡潔に書く」「実際に問題になったらプロファイラでチェック」「パレートの法則があるので初めから根を詰めない」。まずは色々なデザインパターンを見ていきたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: はい。ちなみにデザインパターンというよりは、この場合YAGNI原則と言われる"愚直な書き方にしてしまいましょう"という考え方が適切かもしれません。なぜなら、抽象化しなければ読み取れないというよりは、単に"必要以上に難しいことをしない"事が大事なシーンだからです。

Comment: 余談ですが、プログラマーは、CPUスペックやメモリー容量を低めに見積もってしまい、設計段階から過剰にチューニングしがちな人が多かったです。（老人の繰り言になりますが、8bit, 16bitを経験している人は特に）いまはCPUスペックもメモリー容量も十分すぎるほどある事が多いので、@rugamaga さんが仰る様に、素直に・読みやすく・あとからチューニングしやすい（プロファイラーが賢くなっているので、ボトルネックがさがしやすい）様に書くことが一番大事だと思います。

Answer (score -1):

そういうのを決めるのが「設計」といいます。あれこれのトレードオフを見繕って、こっちの選択肢だとこういうメリットデメリットがある、あっちの選択肢だとああいうメリットデメリットがある云々、だからこうしてみるか。ってことで。

常に状況が変わるといっても人間側がついてこれなきゃゲームにならないわけです。数秒間同じ、ってのはコンピュータから見ると超絶長い時間なわけで、その間は再計算しても結果が同じであるってことなら計算結果を RAM に保存しておくことをお勧めします。再計算すると CPU がアクティブになる＝消費電力が増え電池の残量が早く減る、ってことですよね。 RAM は使っても使わなくても消費電力は変わりません。

> CPU負荷時間よりも一般的にメモリ参照時間がボトルネックになるならば

CPU で計算する際には必ずメモリの読み込み・書き込みがあるわけですが？

Comment: 「ですが？」の部分は見る人によっては挑発的に聞こえるかもしれません……。また「メモリ」が何を指しているかによってこの部分は必ずしも正しくないなと思いました。

Comment: 1点指摘させていただきたいです。実は携帯機においてRAMを使うと消費メモリが上がります。また、その消費メモリはそれなりに大きくなる傾向があるのです。これはメモリセルは確保している限りリフレッシュが必要で、そのたびに電力を消費してしまうためです。ただし、こういった問題も実際の計測を経て最適なバランス(＝最適化)を行う物かもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。毎度CPU処理した値（CPU上のキャッシュメモリ）、予め計算しといた中間値（別途増設のメインメモリ）になります。インスタンス変数はメインメモリ上なんだろうなと勝手なイメージをしております（ある関数処理結果の値は次の関数処理では過去の値になる感覚です）。質問は「都度マップ上の座標を踏まえた計算」になりますので、今の値だけが必要で、前回値を保管する必要がない状況になります。プログラム言語によっては何気ない処理でも裏方で物凄くメモリ管理していると思いますが、そこまで私の知識が追いついておりません。CPU、キャッシュメモリ、メインメモリの電力と処理結果時間を手に取るように分かれば良いのですが、雑学的に知っておけたらなと思った次第です。

Comment: 不備がありました。「コーディングルールのライン引き」で知っておけたらなと思った次第です。